# Not able to display array in Object

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where a call to my API returns an object that also contains an array of objects.

Essentially:

```
   {
      "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd4",
      "lastname": "Lane",
      "firstname": "Panny",
      "__v": 0,
      "contacts": [
         {
            "name": "rick jevers",
            "age": 25,
            "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd5"
         }
      ]
   },
```

I thought the way to display the objects in the array was to use another ng-repeat, like so:

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="clear:both; padding:30px;">
      <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li ng-repeat="item in sample.post">
        <strong>
          {{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}
        </strong>  
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li ng-repeat="contact in sample.post.contacts">
            {{contact.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second `ng-repeat`, you are already inside another `ng-repeat`, which means you already have the current object (item) that is being repeated say the first object in the array for example, Hence, directly use it in the second `ng-repeat` like below :

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li ng-repeat="contact in item.contacts">
        {{contact.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**Working Demo :**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.sample = {};
  $scope.sample.post = [{
      "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd4",
      "lastname": "Lane",
      "firstname": "Panny",
      "__v": 0,
      "contacts": [
         {
            "name": "rick jevers",
            "age": 25,
            "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd5"
         }
      ]
   }]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="clear:both; padding:30px;">
      <ul style="list-style: none">
      <li ng-repeat="item in sample.post">
        <strong>
          {{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}
        </strong>  
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li ng-repeat="contact in item.contacts">
            {{contact.name}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you need to figure out *why* it didn't work for you.
`ng-repeat` iterates over an **array** and for each item in the array, it'll repeat the element along with it's child elements in the DOM.

When you write the 1st `ng-repeat`, you are iterating on the main array which contain all the person details. In the next step, you have `contacts` array within each such object, i.e here you want to iterate in the same object's `contacts`.

Take your input:

```
[
{
      "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd4",//person 1
      "lastname": "Lane",
      "firstname": "Panny",
      "__v": 0,
      "contacts": [
         {
            "name": "rick jevers",
            "age": 25,
            "_id": "587bc430e64e9f28a6894dd5"
         }
      ]
   }, 
{
//person 2
}, {
//person 3
}
```

So your 1st `ng-repeat` would be over this array. Next comes `contact`, which is in the same object, so you need to do `ng-repeat` on `contacts`, but in the same object.

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="clear:both; padding:30px;">
  <ul style="list-style: none">
  <li ng-repeat="item in sample.post">
    <strong>
      {{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}
    </strong>  
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <li ng-repeat="contact in item.contacts"><!--iterate over item's contact-->
        {{contact.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```